# perl filehandles in loop error

Tags: perl, loops, filehandle

Trying to split fastq file into many files based on match present in a file so output files can be more than 500. Giving two input files - one for match and other content(fastq). Put match in different files. This code works perfectly but cannot create more than 502 files. Above 502, says cannot make file. Is that the limit of filehandles in loop. I need to create > 502 files at a time. Any solutions? Thanks

```
my @fh_array;
 foreach(@file_names){
    chomp $_;
    local *OUT;
    open (OUT, ">", "$_\.txt") or die "cannot write file";
    push @fh_array, *OUT;

}

    # In for loop, it works
    print $fh_array[0] "Hello";
```

Comment: `... or die "cannot write file '$_.txt': $!";` so that you can see the reason why.

Comment: You may well be hitting a file handle limit. If so, it has nothing to do with the loop. It's a limit on the number of file handles opened (in whatever way) by one process at one time.

Comment: Oh, and having 500+ file handles open at the same time does not seem like a smart idea. Is there any reason you cannot just open the files when you need them?

Comment: you can check the "open files" limit with the shell command ``ulimit -n`` if you are on a linux or unix system

Comment: And you might want to use lexical filehandles and work with those. This whole `local` business seems rather outdated. `foreach(@foo){ open my $fh, '>', "$_.txt" or die $!; push @fhs, $fh; }`

Comment: Error:    Can't use an undefined value as a symbol reference at ./pe-files-check.pl line 141, <R2> line 43917872.

Comment: umimit -u is: 514621

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Trying to split fastq file into many files based on some match so output files can be more than 500. Giving two input files - one for match and other content. Put match in different files.

Comment: Seems fine, but why do you need to open all of them concurrently in that case?

Comment: how big is the input file (in bytes, not lines)?

Comment: It doesn't take that long to open a file. Just open the file before you need to print to it, then close it when you're done printing instead of keep all the files open at once.

Comment: Particularly if it is open for writing - write IO caches nicely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this is a Perl problem. I ran it with 1000 files, no problem. There is a per process limit to the number of open files that you can display (and possibly set) using ulimit.

Comment: please let me know how can I do?

Comment: Try `ulimit -n ulimited`. But you might need root privilege for that.

Comment: with root:    ulimit -n 3000
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Comment: Your sysadmin has restricted you from doing this. You're out of luck. You can probably ask them to assist.

Comment: I have got root access, also tried with admin  ulimit -n 30000
-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

Comment: Now, ulimit -n 3000 worked and same code is working for >500 fh. Thanks. Maybe it will work for 3000 files. If I need > 3000 fh, will spin my head.

Answer (score 0):

While there may be limitations of your system that prevents this many file handles being open at the same time, there is also the fact that this is a brute force solution that is not necessary, or very practical. I will wager that you will not notice a significant performance difference if you simply open a file when you need it, rather than have all of your files open at once.

For example:

```
write_to_file($file, @lines);

sub write_to_file {
    my ($file, @lines) = @_;
    open my $fh, ">>", $file or die "Cannot open file '$file' for appending: $!";
    print $fh @lines;
}
```

Comment: I know that I need to make more than 502 and need to know the order of dile opened so that that it can be filled accordingly because opening later may be difficult to know which opened when to fill.

Comment: @SSh So you are saying that you think that an array with file handles will be easier to keep track of than an array of file names....? Because that is clearly wrong. Order is order, whether it is file names or file handles.

Comment: ok, if I got right- you mean check whole file and make array and print to file. I have got file (to check) with 40M lines and I want to check each line at a same time to match and print to several files at the same time. Otherwise, I need to look for each match in whole file, number of times which will be equal to number of match to search, am I correct?

Comment: @TLP: I would expect a significant difference opening a file each time you want to write a line

Comment: @SSh I'm not quite sure what you mean. It is difficult to give advice with so little info. If I had to write to multiple files, I would open one at the time.

Comment: @TLP: yes, significant in human terms.  opening (and closing) a file is expensive.  42 seconds: `seq 1000000 | perl -wle'while (<>) { open my $fh, ">>", "out"; print $fh $_ }'`  0.3 seconds: `seq 1000000 | perl -wle'open my $fh, ">>", "out"; while (<>) { print $fh $_ }'`

Comment: @TLP: I have got two files one (match file) with file name and corresponding string (strings are unique barcode) to look into file (fastq file) with many strings (4M strings to check which part (substring) is same as in match file). I am matching string that is in the match file and checking in 4M strings. I am passing string from fastq file one by one to loop and checking to all match string, if match to one barcode (will never match to two or more barcodes), printing at the same time to corresponding FH. But, multiple strings goes to same FH if barcode match.

Comment: @ysth http://pastebin.com/3TqEkhQH Shows file handle storage is 44% slower for 1000 file handles. Your code is not equivalent, as it only shows opening one file one time. You should know better.

Comment: you are only printing to each file once there; that's a little different from printing 40 million or 4 million strings (both numbers were given different places here) to 500+ files.  but it is still a fair point; I showed printing to one file a million times, where it it should have been somewhere in the 4000-80000 range.

Answer (score 0):

Psuedo-filehandles do not count against your system limit of open filehandles. Depending on your memory requirements, it might be feasible to write your output to memory and then write your memory to disk (one file at a time) at the end of your script.

For example:

```
my (@fh_array, %output);
foreach my $file_name (@file_names) {
    $output{$file_name} = '';
    open my $fh, '>', \$output{$file_name};
    push @fh_array, $fh;
}

# main part of program, print to handles in @fh_array
... print {$fh_array[185]} "Hello\n" ...

# end of program. Copy from memory to disk with one open fh at a time
close $_ for @fh_array;
foreach my $file_name (keys %output) {
    open my $fh, '>', $file_name;
    print $fh $output{$file_name};
    close $fh;
}
```

There are almost surely better ways to design your program without having to have so many filehandles open simultaneously or to have this extra complexity.